# How to insert a row to a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to use insertRowsAtIndexPaths method to insert a row to a UITableView, but I don't know how to make "indexPaths" property for this method.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create single NSIndexPath using

```
+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSUInteger)row inSection:(NSUInteger)section; // defined in UITableView.h
```

Your code to create and fill indexPaths paramater may look like:

```
NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
for (...) // iterate to get all indexes and section you need
{
   [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:someRow inSection:someSection]];
}
//indexPaths is ready to use
```

Comment: It's useful! Thank so much, Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSIndexPath *) indexPathForRow:(NSUInteger)row andSection:(NSUInteger)section {
    NSUInteger _path[2] = {section, row};
    NSIndexPath *_indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndexes:_path length:2];
    return [_indexPath autorelease];
}
```